# Pandas differences between p2.7 and p3.6

Tags: pandas

I just started a new project, for the first time in python 3. Recycling some code from another python 2.7 project, I have this piece of code

```
    it = df.itertuples()
    ...
    return it.next()
```

Both pandas versions are 0.19.2
In python2 it has the type

```
<itertools.imap object at 0x7fe900a69790>
```

in python3

```
<map object at 0x7f53108cbba8>
```

I checked the docs for my version 
    http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html

but that seems to be for p2.7 only. 
Is there an easy way to to iterate get the next item from a map like this? 
Where can I find documentation?
How different is pandas in py3? Is it tricky to recycle code from 2.x?

Why is pandas different for p2 and p3? Is there a lot of differences so that recycling code will be very tricky?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, looks like next(iterator) is the python 3 way to go instead of it.next()